# I don't understand why Wallet keys are only a little over a kilobyte when the transaction signatures are extreme in size

Tags: security, wallet-security, hacking

I'm asking this question related to bitcoin security. There's a general consensus that it's nearly impossible for a %51 attack on the bitcoin blockchain which isn't generally considered a risk that bitcoin would not be vulnerable to this type of attack but at the same time anyone can connect to the bitcoin blockchain and try to guess as many times as one would initiate using keyword engines like 'John' in Linux. It would be possible in theory to use a mining rig or for that matter a mining facility to be programmed to guess keywords. So why is it not a risk to have a wallet so small in size that one powerful GPU could make the correct guesses in a relatively short time because of connection attempts are unlimited. If this is the case are bitcoin developers any concerned of the necessity to increase the wallet size and would it be a good idea to make wallet sizes increase as the blockchain grows in size to keep pace with advances in silicon chips. My question is why doesn't it make sense to increase the size of the wallet to make bitcoin unhackable?